# Harvard CS51Utils

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to work my way through the labs and problem sets that are available for Harvard's CS 51 course online. However, I've run into a problem in Lab 10 with installing an OCaml package called CS51Utils. When I enter the command `opam pin add CS51Utils https://github.com/cs51/utils.git -y`, which is supposed to install the package, I get the below error:

```
#=== ERROR while compiling CS51Utils.1.0.0 ====================================#
# context     2.0.8 | macos/x86_64 | ocaml-base-compiler.4.12.0 | pinned(git+https://github.com/cs51/utils.git#2c8066ff)
# path        ~/.opam/4.12.0/.opam-switch/build/CS51Utils.1.0.0
# command     ~/.opam/opam-init/hooks/sandbox.sh build dune build -p CS51Utils -j 11
# exit-code   1
# env-file    ~/.opam/log/CS51Utils-2629-2dea01.env
# output-file ~/.opam/log/CS51Utils-2629-2dea01.out
### output ###
# File "bin/dune", line 3, characters 12-20:
# 3 |  (libraries graphics)
#                 ^^^^^^^^
# Error: Library "graphics" not found.
# Hint: try:
#   dune external-lib-deps --missing --no-config --root . --ignore-promoted-rules --default-target @install --always-show-command-line --promote-install-files --release --only-packages CS51Utils -p CS51Utils --profile release -j 11 @install
```

It looks like the error is that the "graphics" library is not found, but not sure what to do about that. I thought I would throw it out here and see if there is any chance anyone here has taken the course and run into this error, or has any ideas about what might be going on.

Comment: Per the [CS51 Ocaml setup guide](https://cs51.io/handouts/setup/), have you tried installing the graphics requirement? `opam install -y graphics`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have stumbled on a bug in the CS51Utils package definition. They use the `graphics` package, per this [`dune` file](https://github.com/cs51/utils/blob/2c8066ffbc981aff2c391035aa372b3cf29679af/bin/dune#L3).

But they don't list the package as a *dependency* in the [`dune-project` file](https://github.com/cs51/utils/blob/2c8066ffbc981aff2c391035aa372b3cf29679af/dune-project#L13) where they list other dependencies.

They need to add `graphics` as a dependency there so that it gets installed automatically in future. I recommend you file a bug report on the repo. Until they do, you can manually install the package with: `opam install graphics`.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like this took care of the problem with installing CS51Utils. I got the message "installed CS51Utils.1.0.0". However, when I open OCAML in the Terminal and type `open CS51Utils ;;` I get an "unbound module" error. So now need to figure out why that is happening. Really appreciate the help with getting the package installed though.

Comment: @AshKetchum use utop which is a better REPL (interactive environment). Install with: `opam install utop`. Then run `utop` to open it up. Then in utop run: `#require "CS51Utils";;` to load the package. Now you can use it.